# Unable to ge results using CASE,AND,OR operators (SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been trying to get the following query to work using `CASE` statement, `OR`/`AND` operators. I would like to get values from E and H:

Query :

```
SELECT CAT_CD, PRD_CD, PTG_CAT, HN, OTC_FL, 
       CASE WHEN PTG_CAT = '1' THEN 'MEGA POWER'
            WHEN PTG_CAT = '2' THEN 'POWER'
            WHEN PTG_CAT = '3' THEN 'NEW'
            WHEN PTG_CAT = '4' THEN 'OTHERS'
            ELSE HN = 'H' AND 'E' THEN 'POWERHERBALEYE'
       END AS "BRAND_CATEGORY"
FROM PROD_TG_CAT
```

> ELSE HN = 'H' AND 'E' THEN 'POWERHERBALEYE'
>                     *
>       ERROR at line 6:
>       ORA-00905: missing keyword

```
 TABLE STRUCTURE:

 SQL> DESC PROD_TG_CAT
 Name                            Null?    Type
 ------------------------------- -------- ----
 DIV_CD                          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(1)
 PTG_CAT                         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(1)
 CAT_CD                          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(2)
 PRD_CD                          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(4)
 HN                                       VARCHAR2(1)
 OTC_FL                                   VARCHAR2(1)
```

Some of the results from the main table prod_tg_cat:

```
D P CA PRD_ H O
- - -- ---- - -
1 4 07 1011
1 4 08 1100
1 4 26 1003 H
2 2 06 4032
1 4 07 1008 E O
1 4 14 1011
1 4 08 1206
1 4 08 1091



D P CA PRD_ H O  
1 4 07 1008 E O
```

The result should display like this:

Result:

```
    26  1003    4   H       OTHERS >>> HERBAL
    06  4032    2           POWER
    07  1008    4   E   O   OTHERS >>> EYE and OTC
    14  1011    4           OTHERS
    08  1206    4           OTHERS
```

Here are two more queries I have tried in order to get the result:

```
SELECT CAT_CD, PRD_CD, PTG_CAT, HN, OTC_FL, 
       CASE WHEN PTG_CAT = '1' THEN 'MEGA POWER'
            WHEN PTG_CAT = '2' THEN 'POWER'
            WHEN PTG_CAT = '3' THEN 'NEW'
            WHEN PTG_CAT = '4' THEN 'OTHERS'
            ELSE 'POWERHERBALEYE'
       END AS "BRAND_CATEGORY"
FROM PROD_TG_CAT

SELECT CAT_CD, PRD_CD, PTG_CAT, HN, OTC_FL, 
       CASE WHEN HN = 'H' THEN 'HERBAL'
            WHEN HN = 'E' THEN 'EYE'
            WHEN PTG_CAT = '3' THEN 'NEW'
            WHEN PTG_CAT = '4' THEN 'OTHERS'
            ELSE 'POWER'
       END AS "HERBAL&EYE"
FROM PROD_TG_CAT
```

Thanks!
Regards
Iftekhar

Comment: Do you want "WHEN HN IN ('H','E') THEN..."?

Comment: Those are some meaningful column names

Comment: @jarlh yes something like that if you can come up with the query.do share it here.thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need multiple CASEs like this:

```
SELECT CAT_CD, PRD_CD, PTG_CAT, HN, OTC_FL, 
       CASE WHEN PTG_CAT = '1' THEN 'MEGA POWER'
            WHEN PTG_CAT = '2' THEN 'POWER'
            WHEN PTG_CAT = '3' THEN 'NEW'
            WHEN PTG_CAT = '4' THEN 'OTHERS'
       END,
       CASE HN 
         WHEN 'H' THEN 'HERBAL'
         WHEN 'E' THEN 'EYE'
       END,
       CASE OTC_FL 
         WHEN 'O' THEN 'OTC'
       END 
FROM PROD_TG_CAT
```

If you want a single column you must concat those CASEs:

```
SELECT CAT_CD, PRD_CD, PTG_CAT, HN, OTC_FL, 
       CASE WHEN PTG_CAT = '1' THEN 'MEGA POWER'
            WHEN PTG_CAT = '2' THEN 'POWER'
            WHEN PTG_CAT = '3' THEN 'NEW'
            WHEN PTG_CAT = '4' THEN 'OTHERS'
            ELSE ''
       END ||
       CASE HN 
         WHEN 'H' THEN ' >>> HERBAL'
         WHEN 'E' THEN ' >>> EYE'
         ELSE ''
       END ||
       CASE OTC_FL  
         WHEN 'O' THEN ' and OTC'
         ELSE ''
       END 
FROM PROD_TG_CAT
```

Comment: ,thanks a lot.hope this will solve the query.i will get back to you the soonest.

Answer (score 3):

You should check this reference to CASE expressions again, as your error seems to be a malformed ELSE expression:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm

You could try this query, maybe it solves your problem:

```
SELECT CAT_CD, PRD_CD, PTG_CAT, HN, OTC_FL, 
   CASE WHEN PTG_CAT = '1' THEN 'MEGA POWER'
        WHEN PTG_CAT = '2' THEN 'POWER'
        WHEN PTG_CAT = '3' THEN 'NEW'
        WHEN PTG_CAT = '4' THEN 'OTHERS'
        WHEN HN = 'H' OR HN = 'E' THEN 'POWERHERBALEYE'
   END AS "BRAND_CATEGORY"
FROM PROD_TG_CAT
```

Comment: thank you i will your query.thanks for the CASE expressions link.